# Is Newton's 3rd law only valid when bodies are in contact?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

All the examples explaining 3rd law in my textbook are instances when bodies are in contact, like when we walk for example; we press the ground with our feet, so the ground exerts an equal and opposite force and the horizontal component of this force enables us to move forward. And it makes sense; because from what I have gathered so far, its electrostatic repulsion at play at an atomic level. But it doesn't make sense if the bodies are not in contact. In deriving formulas later on when we assume a system of ***n*** particles, for example, we consider that the internal forces cancel out due to 3rd law. I don't really understand this. Can someone please explain?

Comment: gravity is an example, the force that the earth does to the moon is the same as that the moon makes on the earth

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't make sense when bodies are not in contact? It should be pointed out that the atoms that you mention in your question aren't actually "in contact" either.

Answer (score 3):

Bodies do not have to be in contact for Newton's 3rd law to apply. Gravity is the classic example - the Earth attracts the moon with $F = GMm/r^2$, and the Moon attracts the Earth with the same force.

Other examples could be Coulomb attraction or repulsion; both bodies feel the force.

Answer (score 3):

In non-contact forces, such as gravitation or the Coulomb force, an object with mass or charge respectively produces a **field** that permeates through space, which helps communicate these forces. It's a property of space, or the universe, to embody these fields, you might say.
 So in a sense, it's this field that acts analogous to a rope to exert these forces, rather than the objects exerting the forces themselves(of course **you** are the one who pulls on the rope in a tug of war, but it's the rope that ultimately pulls on the other person).

The point to note here is that- these fields are indiscriminate towards who or what is producing them, and there is no question of who's exerting them first, as you can communicate with the field only if you produce your own field of the same nature; and when these fields of two bodies interact, they interact in a way to give a single force arising from the strengths of both the fields. Eg: $\vec F =\frac{ \mathbf q_1  \mathbf q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}$, $q_1$ and $q_2 \propto$ strength of the fields

Therefore, the singular interaction/rope formed 'wants' to pull/push on the two bodies with the same amount of force. It can't be a one way thing- you pull on another object with a rope, you'll get pulled in too.

> we consider that the internal forces cancel out due to 3rd law

In a system of ***n*** particles, the $i^{th}$ particle is exerting a force $\vec F_{ij}$ on the $j^{th}$ particle. By the explainaition aforementioned, the $j^{th}$ particle exerts a force $\vec F_{ji} =- \vec F_{ij}$ on the $i^{th}$ particle. In the system of particles $i$ and $j$,
$$\vec F_{net} = \vec F_{ij} + \vec F_{ji} = 0$$
$$\therefore \sum_i^n F_{net} = 0$$

The implication is that, by Newton's third law, internal forces cancel out and the acceleration of the centre of mass of the system of ***n*** particles with no external forces acting on it, is zero.